# How much additional product forms when small amounts of reactants are added to a reaction at equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

I am not able to understand how to determine the exact amount of additional product formed when additional reactant is added to an equilibrium reaction.

For example consider the reaction:

$$\ce{CO2 + H2 <=> CO + H2O}$$

and suppose the number of moles of $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{CO}$, and $\ce{H2O}$ at equilibrium are $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ respectively. $K=1$ for simplicity.

Now how do I determine the amount $\ce{CO2}$ to be added to double the amount of $\ce{CO}$ produced.

I have tried by writing the equation for the equilibrium constant and keeping the amounts of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ constant but it didn't work out.

What I had done is (where $x$ is the new number of moles of equilibrium)

$$K=\frac{c\times d}{a\times b}= \frac{2c\times d}{b\times x}$$

This gives me $x=2a$ but after this I'm not able to proceed any further.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Chem.SE! This looks like a homework question. Could you please edit the question to show how you tried to solve it? Also please read out homework policy [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange).

Comment: Note that you can use MathJAx to typeset maths and chemistry so that it looks appropriate. I have edited your post to do so. Please visits https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here to learn how to do it for yourself.

Comment: You could try with a simpler reaction first, say A=B with initial A as $a_0$ and at equilibrium let amount $x_e$ have reacted. Write down the equilibrium constant and solve for $x_e$. When you have method try with your reaction, its just algebraically messier.

Comment: I have been able to do it for simpler reactions involving only one reactant and product but I'm not able to apply the same strategy for more complex ones. @porphyrin